# How to include the GoogleMaps.apk file while extending MapActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapactivity

I need a help, In my eclipse, I have extended MapActivity to display google maps. Now if i run my program, there exists an error that

> [2011-08-27 18:47:42 - GoogleMaps] Could not find GoogleMaps.apk!

and i dont have any other errors in program.
How to overcome this Bug?

Comment: do you have maps installed on the device you are trying to run on? As far as I know you aren't going to be able to supply your own copy of the maps apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Android n.n Platform library? I think you need the Android n.n Google APIs library.

It can be downloaded via the Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is run on a device that does not come with the Google Maps app, then there is nothing you can do. It is owned by Google, and if the device does not come with it you cannot provide it yourself.