# How to use Google map in Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to display the Google map on my Emulator. I'm using 2.2 (Google Inc). I'm having all the functions for displaying the map. But, it shows the error about         `[2011-08-29 13:27:49 - GoogleMaps] Could not find GoogleMaps.apk`

What can i do for this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure that you have need permissions in Manifest.xml
2. Restart Emulator
3. [How to include the GoogleMaps.apk file while extending MapActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215028/how-to-include-the-googlemaps-apk-file-while-extending-mapactivity)

Comment: I edited this question, but really: if all you can provide is a link to another question, then it's better suited as a comment.